# How can I change from TRUE to FALSE after a minute?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing an API for voting. I have a method which starts the voting session and the session should stands open for 1 minute, then close after time.
Closing the session means that I have to change the method `setIsSessionOpen` to `FALSE`.
While the session is open, user should be able to vote. Inside my `SessionVote` object there are two fields which represents the vote (`votedYes` and `votedNo` where both will be storing the each vote's count.).

Here what I did so far and it's in service class:

```
    public SessionVote openSession(String agendaSubject, Integer sessionId){
        SessionVote sessionVote = findBySessionVoteId(sessionId);
        Optional<Agenda> agenda = getAgendaBySubject(agendaSubject);
        if (agenda.isPresent()) {
            sessionVote.setAgenda(agenda.get());
            sessionVote.setIsSessionOpen(true);
            sessionVote.setStartedTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            LOGGER.info("The session ID {} is opened and started at {}. The subject for voting is: {}", sessionVote.getSessionVoteId(), sessionVote.getStartedTime(), sessionVote.getAgenda().getSubject());
            return sessionVote;
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("No subject was found");
            throw new NoSubjectFoundException(Constants.NO_SUBJECT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

I ommitted some code to be cleaner and easier to understand my question but I can add more info if is necessary.

Comment: what's the question? how to `setIsSessionOpen` to `false`?

Comment: Is the user interface a GUI or console I/O? If a GUI, is it based on SWING, JavaFX, or what?

Comment: It's a spring boot application. My controller calls the service where the method above within.
AssemblyController -> assemblyService.openSession(agendaSubject, sessionId)

Comment: If you have wait for the user to type a response and press "enter", because of blocking I/O, you can't check the time. But, if you continuously check the time, you can't check for user input. The way around this is to use separate threads. The answer from Ellott Frisch does that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, start a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to invoke `setIsSessionOpen(false)` after a minute.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sessionVote.setIsSessionOpen(false);
    }
};
t.schedule(tt, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
```